# Has this weak version of Erdős Conjecture on arithmetic progressions been proven, or is it still an open problem?

Tags: divergent-series, pigeonhole-principle, arithmetic-progressions, open-problem, erdos-conjecture

This question is motivated by [Erdős conjecture on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions). It is a weaker version of Erdős Conjecture, but I do not know how to prove it.

Erdős conjecture on arithmetic progressions states that, "If $A$ is a large set, then $A$ contains arithmetic progressions of every length."

The following conjecture states that, "If $A$ is a large set, then $A$ contains *quasi-arithmetic progressions* of every length."

If $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ is a large set in the sense that

$$ \sum_{n\in A} \frac{1}{n} = \infty,$$

then for every $k\in\mathbb{N},$ there exists $r,s\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1},\ $ and $\ \lbrace{a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_k\rbrace} \subset A,\ $ such that

$$ a_j \in [r + (j-1)s, r + js ] \quad \forall\ j\in \lbrace{1,\ldots, k\rbrace}. $$

Comment: What a great question.  Upvoted!  Can you explain more about how/why it is weaker than Erdos' conjecture?

Comment: It is "obviously" weaker than Erdos' conjecture, in the sense that, if Erdos Conjecture is true, then my conjecture is true, but not the other way round. I.e. if my conjecture is true, then this would not imply that Erdos' conjecture is true.

Comment: Wouldn't _your_ conjecture be the same as it is, if you used $\Bbb{N}$ or $\Bbb{Z}$ instead of $\Bbb{R}_{\geq 1}$?  Not saying the same as Erdos, but just "simplified" if you use those smaller sets.

Comment: No, I think with $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$, I allow some more options, Like if $r=1,$ and $s=1.3,\ $ then $a_1 \in \{1,2\},\ a_2 = 3,\ a_3 = 4,\ a_4 \in\{4,5\},\ \ldots,\ $ which is a pattern you don't see if we replace $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If you go through some of the more annoying/tedious algebra, it's equivalent to the existence of $\{a_1,\cdots,a_k\}\subset A$ with $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_k$ such that $\min_{j,m\in\{1,\cdots,k\},1+j-m<0}\frac{a_j-a_m}{1+j-m}\ge\max_{j,m\in\{1,\cdots,k\},1+j-m>0}\frac{a_j-a_m}{1+j-m}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a short proof of this result. Suppose $A$ does not satisfy the conclusion of the theorem for some $k$.

Claim: for every interval $I$ of length $k^s$, the cardinality of $A \cap I$ is at most $(k - 1)^s$.

Proof: Induction on $s$. The base case $s = 1$ is trivial. For the induction step, let $I = [r, r + k^s)$ and $I_i = [r + i k^{s - 1}, r + (i + 1) k^{s - 1})$. By the assumption, one of $I_0, \cdots, I_{k - 1}$ does not contain any $A$. Now use induction hypothesis on the rest of the $I_i$'s. $\square$

Now note that
$$\sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a} = \sum_i \sum_{a \in A \cap [k^{i - 1}, k^i)} \frac{1}{a} \leq \sum_i \frac{(k - 1)^i}{k^{i - 1}}  < \infty.$$